# How to map a multidimensional array (using Underscore)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, underscore.js

I have a large, multidimensional array of JSON objects that I want to map through (using Underscore). For example:

```
var dummyData = [
    [{title: 'a'},{title : 'b'}],
    [{title: 'a'},{title : 'b'}],
    [{title: 'a'},{title : 'b'}],
    [{title: 'a'},{title : 'b'}]
];
```

For the function body of the `_.map`, I want to run each JSON object through a Backbone Model constructor. So far, I've tried something like this to accomplish this:

```
_.map(dummyData, function() {
    _.each(dummyData, function(el, i) {
        // run each object through the constructor
    }
})
```

I'm getting caught up on the `_.each`, though - since `dummyData` isn't actually the 'list' that I want to loop through.

Or am I thinking about this wrong altogether?

Comment: Do you want the result to be an Array of Arrays like your input?

Comment: Yes. Exactly the same as the input, but each object would be a Backbone Model.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Iterate over the elements of `dummyData`, with `_.map` like this

```
_.map(dummyData, function(currentDummyData) {
    return _.map(currentDummyData, function(el, i) {
        // run each object through the constructor
    })
});
```

`dummyData` is an Array of Arrays. When you use `_.map` with that, it picks up each array in the array of arrays and passes to the function, which we accept with `function(currentDummyData) {..}`.

Inside that function, we again `_.map` that array, because it is still an array. So, we iterate that to get individual elements and pass them to the function `function(el, i) {..}`, where new Backbone models are created.

**Note:** You have to return the result of `_.map`, like in the answer. Because, `_.map` expects the function called to return an object and all the returned objects will be gathered to create a new array.

For example,

```
console.log(_.map(dummyData, function(currentDummyData) {
    return _.map(currentDummyData, function(el, i) {
        return {title: el.title + el.title};
    })
}));
```

will produce

```
[ [ { title: 'aa' }, { title: 'bb' } ],
  [ { title: 'aa' }, { title: 'bb' } ],
  [ { title: 'aa' }, { title: 'bb' } ],
  [ { title: 'aa' }, { title: 'bb' } ] ]
```